# Readin a space separated line using Scanner in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Suppose I have a lines like :

03 674 67468734 467364
56 473 36474643 647632

56 787 68686888 648638

How do I read it into a String temp using scanner in java ?And I would also mention that at the end of this line there is a space.And evrytime the each line is being read into temp and after performing some opertation with temp, the same reading operation is being carried out on temp for the next string.

Comment: How are you constructing your Scanner? By default this should just work as you desire. The default delimiter (char sequence between tokens) is one or more whitespace characters, so the Scanner should not produce any additional tokens between "647632" and "56".

Answer (score 1):

use [scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) default deliminator is space.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142");
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
```

Comment: well thats not the only string ,the actual pattern is like this :03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 \n
03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 \n 
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 \n
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 \n
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 \n
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 \n

Comment: Scanner takes string as parameter in the constructor so you can do this for any string with deliminator

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read the whole line.

Comment: I tried but whenever i am pressing enter in the input ,it is reading a blankline which i dont want